# git clone could not resolve proxy

Tags: git, github

Hi I'm trying to clone a repository using git clone.
However I get the message:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.name.com': Could not resolve proxy: proxy.name.com
```

I've already tried setting the proxy in the config file using

`git config --global http.proxy http://myuser:mypass..@proxy.name.com:8080`

and the following appears in the .gitconfig file:
`

```
[http]
    proxy = http://myuser:mypass..@proxy.name.com:8080
```

`
The repository can be cloned from other devices, so I'd appreciate if someone cold tell me if there is something else I could be missing, or another cause why the repository can't be cloned from this PC.

Comment: Can you ping your proxy? It sounds like a networking issue at a layer that is not application.

Comment: Yes, I get response when I ping my proxy

Comment: `could not resolve` is a name server error, and typically means that there's a network glitch. Normally a name like `some.host.com` gets an immediate error (
("does not exist") or an immediate resolution ("ipv4 address 127.0.0.1"), but sometimes DNS is down or being denial-of-service-attacked or whatever and your computer says "I can't get an answer, try again later".

Comment: If ping works now, retry, and things should probably work.

Comment: Still nothing, ping works but I get the same error. I'll wait then, thank you!

Comment: Hm, well, things here should be *consistent:* either the host name resolves and the proxy connection should proceed (and you'll either have things work or get a different error), or the host name doesn't resolve and `ping <proxy-name>` should also give you a "could not resolve" error. So *something* is hinky, but now you have to dive into your OS's particulars.