# Git clone gives error: Could not resolve proxy

Tags: git, proxy, git-clone

I tried to clone a github repository, but it gave me the following error:

`fatal: unable to access 'link was here': Could not resolve proxy: proxy`

Could someone help me how to fix this? I already tried to search on google, but it didnt help me out..

I tried: `git config --global --unset http.proxy`
It didn't gave an output, and when i tried git clone again, i got the same error..

`git config -l --show-origin` gave me this:
`file:/home/user/.gitconfig     https.proxy=`

Comment: [Perhaps you and this person have the same problem going on.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74290331/1256452)

Comment: @torek I think so, but there is no solution either..